# How do I compile ndiswrapper?

Tags: install-from-source, ndiswrapper

I have been working for a good 2 days now trying every forum post I could find when it comes to **ndiswrapper**.

I can get it installed but get the error `module ndiswrapper not found` keeps coming up. In my travels, this is a bug in the installer and I have to build it from source. I have no clue how that works.

Is there anyone out there that can give me an idea of where to start? I don't even know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

Download the file to your desktop here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ndiswrapper/files/

Drag and drop the file to your desktop and right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Open a terminal and, with a temporary ethernet connection, do:

```
    sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
    cd Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.58rc1
    sudo su
    make
    make install
    modprobe ndiswrapper
    exit
```

Packages compiled from source need to be re-compiled when a newer kernel version is installed by Update Manager:

```
    cd Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.58rc1
    sudo su
    make clean
    make
    make install
    modprobe ndiswrapper
    exit
```

Please let us know if you encounter an error.